# How can I divide or split woocommerce prices?

Tags: woocommerce, split, price, divide

How is it possible to divide or split the price (sale or normal, depending on the default) as shown in the attached image?
[Final_Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls4Nq.jpg)

Comment: You can paste images in stackoverflow it self please try that next time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I added with 100% width the full price, which then made the current price drop down to the next line. I just added it to the style.css in my child theme.

```
.woocommerce div.product p.price del, .woocommerce div.product span.price del {
width: 100%;
}
```